# Selenium - Wait for OutOfBound element C#

Tags: c#, selenium, action, indexoutofboundsexception, webdriverwait

I use Selenium C# binding and I want to click over the addToCart button.

First, I'm waiting the button appears on the page with ExpectedConditions.ToBeClickable.

Then, I need to scroll down the page to be able to click over the button. I used the Selenium.Interactions class but it work as well with js executor.

```
private By addToCartBy = By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement addToCart = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(addToCartBy));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(addToCart);
action.Perform();
addToCart.Click();
```

When I perform this test with Chrome driver, the page loads and the navigator scroll down to the element addToCart and click it but I'm unable to get the button working properly.

When I use Firefox driver, it raise this exception:
`OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : '(1435, 998) is out of bounds of viewport width (1920) and height (966)'`and I'm unable to click over the button

Most of the time, the click will be performed but no action will follow from this. If I want the button to work properly (go the the cart), I need to put a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` to be effective or a `Console.ReadLine()`. Even if I disable the automation click and I do it manually, the button don't always proceed.

**How can I make sure my element addToCart is displayed after I moved to Element? *in a way to click it when he's ready.***

Thank you, Eelke Johnson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some of the scenarios, you can use not

> IWebElement.Click();

but

> IWebElement.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

I had some scenarios, where just **Click()** didn't work for me.Maybe this will help in your situation.

Comment: Hi, today I restarted my computer and tested your method and it only worked on firefoxwebdriver but not on chromewebdriver. Furthermore it work with this snippet only on FirefoxDriver:`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            IWebElement addToCart = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(addToCartBy));
            addToCart.Click();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a couple of things.

- To invoke `MoveToElement()`, [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) as `ElementToBeClickable()` is overkill. Instead you can do away with `ElementIsVisible()`.
- While invoking `Click()` as per best practices you need to invoke [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) inconjunction with *ExpectedConditions* as `ElementToBeClickable()`.
- So effectively, your code block will be:

  ```
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.MoveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button")))).Perform();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. The code you provided executed exactly the same as what I wrote earlier. What do you mean by overkill? I just want to be sure with this snippet that the button is present on the page before I apply any actions over it. Secondly, I used ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable on the button and the click was performed but nothings happened.

Comment: @EelkeJohnson _overkill_ -> over cautious. To ensure _the button is present on the page_ you need `ElementIsVisible()`. _ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable_ is needed only while you invoke `click()`